# How to call a variable declared in a PHP function somewhere else in the code

Tags: php, variables

```
function my_function() {
    $var1 = "123";
    $var2 = "abc";
    return $var1;
}
```

Sometimes I want to use `$var2` but calling `my_function()` will simply return what the function returns ( `$var1` ).

Is there any trick to retrieve the `$var2` data ? maybe `my_function($var2)` ..

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the arguments [`by reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), e.g.

```
$var1 = "";
$var2 = "";

function my_function(&$var1, &$var2) {
                   //^       ^ See here
    $var1 = "123";
    $var2 = "abc";

}

my_function($var1, $var2);
//Now you can use $var1 and $var2 for you next function with the new values.
```

And if you want to read more about references in general see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Appreciated @Rizier123 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$var1 = '321';
echo $var1; // will be '321' obviously
$myVar = my_function();
function my_function()
{
    $var1 = '123';
    return $var1;
}
echo $var1; // will be '321'
echo $myVar; // will be '123';
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is declaring $var2 as a global inside the function.

```
$var2 = "hello";
function my_function() {
    global $var2;
    $var1 = "123";
    $var2 = "abc";
    return $var1;
}
```

Now my_function() will be able to access $var2 declared outside its scope and change its value.